# Input go down after I changed his value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I never seen this problem before, hope some can help.
When I change input value attribution from `S` to `G` using jquery the input go down.

**Edit:** I found the problem, I just needed to add to the main div of the inputs this css:

```
display:inline-flex;
```

```js
$('body').on("click", "#submit", function() {
  $('#input1').attr('value', 'G');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="inputs" id="input1" type="button" value='S' maxlength="1" />
<input class="inputs" id="input2" type="button" value='T' maxlength="1" />

<input type="submit" id="submit" maxlength="1" value="change"/>
```

This code is almost the same to my code (instead of my inputs css)
the result in my code: (image)
[image]

you can see in the image how to inputs that I changed their value go down, and the empty inputs stay in place.

Comment: Working fine in the snippet

Comment: @AshayMandwarya I know, the snippet its almost like my code but without my css. see the image

Comment: Provide that also please

Comment: @AshayMandwarya my fault, its not connects to css, its another problem (I removed my css and check, the problem still been.)

Comment: It the origin of the problem isn't in your CSS, then how come the snippet works fine?

Comment: because its not the full code.. its long system @ItaiSteinherz

Comment: the execution is fine as per the code. But what is your requirement??

Comment: your blank inputs have no value. You can give them a space as value. Then all inputs are aligned

Comment: @Sushil see post edit, I successed!

Comment: Could you add your solution as an answer to help others?

Comment: `$('#input1').attr('value', 'G');` the value of `#input1` is changing as per the event fired. Whats the problem??